# Stuck with connectivity PHP and MySQL in rhel 7.3

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on PHP and MySQL environment in rhel7.3. And I got another problem with my connectivity. I am unable to create a connection between both of them.
i got the error.

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2059] Authentication plugin
>   'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded:
>   /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory .

And code is as follow

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    password = "Gstadmin@123";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=test", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       echo "Connected successfully";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: try by `$conn = new mysqli()`

Comment: I have try $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "Gstadmin@123", "GloBioProd"); but not working but same code is working in ubuntu.

Comment: you are tying this in `windows`?

Comment: no I am trying this code in Redhat (rhel 7.3).

Comment: Look at https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/php-mysql-connect/